# Navigator.sendBeacon() stacking on Single Page Application issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

I am developing SPA like Laracast, Udemy, or any other Learning Manage System.
Using Inertia.js and Vue 3
I am sending a [Navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) before closing/switching tab to control watchtime of the video.

After the first load, it works fine (Sending one rq) but after navigating through the page or redirecting to the next video looks like beacons keep stacking.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdJ3w.png)
Only one of these requests should happen here rest of them indicates how many videos I visited before.

I assume that on the none SPA page that problem won't occur because the page reloads and beacons are clearing.

As I am using [lifecycle.js](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) I tried to remove the listener

Code I used:

```
const sendBeacon = () => {
    const url = '/api/video/${props.currentLesson.media.id}/progress'
    const timeLine = { progress: video.value.currentTime, duration: video.value.duration }

    if (event.newState !== 'hidden') return

    let data = new Blob([JSON.stringify(timeLine)], { type: 'application/json' })

    navigator.sendBeacon(url, data)
}


lifecycle.addEventListener('statechange', sendBeacon);
```

Also tried partial reload from inertia.js.

Is there any chance to clear beacons?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Beacons do not need "clearing", as `Navigator.sendBeacon()` doesn't "stack up" to begin with - that is a one-time request, and not something that would repeat on its own. _You_ must have done something, that causes this stacking up in the first place.

Comment: I uploaded the code I use. Any idea what could I do wrong?

Comment: *I tried to remove the listener* - it may not have succeeded then. You should show more code, it's often referred as [mre]